# Is Silvio Dante wearing a wig in The Sopranos?

Tags: casting, costume, the-sopranos

In *The Sopranos*, behind the scenes, Silvio actor Steven Van Zandt gave up his trademark bandana for an equally signature well-coiffed pompadour toupee.

But within the continuity of *The Sopranos*, is Sil wearing a hair piece?

Was Silvio ever referenced or hinted to be bald in the original TV series? Or is that suggestion [anti-Italian discrimination](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-anti-italian-discrimination)?

Another well-known rug famously [*does* exist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvcFJ9o86pY&t=31s) within the Sopranos canon:

> **Christopher Moltisanti**: Aahh! Holy shit! I had no idea. Did you?
> **Tony Soprano**: Course I did. You're so high on scag, you wouldn't know if he had your mother's muff on his head.

I'm interested in answers for both for the original TV series canon, exclusive, and those including the prequel film *The Many Saints of Newark* or other post-TV sources.

Answer (score 3):

This [blog](https://www.hairtx.com/celebrity-hair-transplant/steve-van-zandt-the-sopranos-and-his-hairpiece/), written back in 2011 and run by a hair transplant doctor, seems to think it's intentional.

> First, the hairline is too straight. A natural hairline is never as
> straight as Silvio’s. Second, the hairline is just too darn low. Many
> individuals who wear hairpieces love to wear them in a prepubescent
> position. If they would simply wear them higher they would look so
> much more natural. Silvio’s hairpiece is very low. Third, his hairline
> does not match his receded temples. If the hairline were adjusted
> higher or if he had a hair transplant just into the temple area he
> would look much more natural.

However, during the run of The Sopranos, it was never mentioned that Silvio's hair was a wig.

Answer (score 1):

[As explained here](https://www.looper.com/621140/small-details-you-missed-in-the-many-saints-of-newark/):

> Longtime Bruce Springsteen guitarist Steven Van Zandt starred as Silvio Dante in *"The Sopranos,"* and it was obvious from the pilot that he was sporting a mega toupee. **But who was going to have guts to call him out on it? After all, he was Tony's consigliere and best buddy.**
>
> Even so, those fans longing for official confirmation of Silvio's balding noggin finally get a look at it in *"The Many Saints of Newark."* Played by John Magaro — who earlier this year played the young version of Harvey Keitel-portrayed gangster Meyer Lansky in the biopic *"Lansky"* — **Silvio and his combover hairstyle appear in the film, as well as scenes where he's wearing a bouffant hairpiece. To top things off, there's a hilarious scene in the film that shows the early failings of Silvio's toupee.**
>
> Presumably the techniques that held Silvio's hairdo together in *"The Sopranos"* advanced quite a bit since the early '70s to prevent any embarrassing moments. That still doesn't take away the combover and toupee scenes in *"The Many Saints of Newark,"* which provide amusing homages to Silvio's larger-than-life mane in the series.

---

[David Chase had this to say](https://www.vulture.com/2021/10/decoding-many-saints-of-newarks-parallels-with-the-sopranos.html):

> In conversations for a ***New York Magazine*** piece, Chase told me that the question of whether Silvio’s hair was organic or artificial never came up when they were making the show. “I don’t think we established it one way or the other,” he said. The most logical assumption is that nobody commented on the hairpiece because Silvio was sensitive about it, and if anyone was foolish enough to violate that taboo, they might end up in “witness protection” like Richie Aprile and Ralphie Cifaretto.